# Get collection of tokens from a CodeMirror doc

Tags: codemirror

I am trying to get a collection of all matched tokens from a doc.

Basically, want to know the total number of occurrences for the term "function" or "var" or any other token I have setup in a document.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the [`runmode`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addon_runmode) addon is the easiest way to do this.